# How to retrieve elements with join query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a problem with sum detailed join with `$graphLookUp` and `$map` but the items retrieves double array :S, there is a way to group the elements in a sum?

This is an example of my collection:

```json
/* 1 */
{

    "type" : "Fase1",
    "total" : 100,
    "key" : "A6E19D93-8546-4A3A-8887-E23C301A290F",
},

/* 2 */
{
    "type" : "Fase1",
    "total" : 340.80,
    "key": "85547A5B-623B-4408-9B3E-26F9B368B2C7"
},
/* 3 */
{
    "type" : "Fase2",
    "key": "F6307773-A6EF-41D4-A2F3-0FE55543846E"
    "complement" : {
        "payments" : [ 
            {
                "amount" : 20,
                "documentsRelated" : [ 
                    {
                        "keyId" : "85547A5B-623B-4408-9B3E-26F9B368B2C7",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "amount" : 15,
                "documentsRelated" : [ 
                    {
                        "keyId" : "85547A5B-623B-4408-9B3E-26F9B368B2C7",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
}
```

I need to get the information in a list with the sum of type `Phase2`

```json
/* 1 */
{
    "type" : "Fase1",
    "total" : 100,
    "key" : "A6E19D93-8546-4A3A-8887-E23C301A290F",
},
/* 2 */
{
    "type" : "Fase1",
    "total" : 340.80,
    "key": "85547A5B-623B-4408-9B3E-26F9B368B2C7",
    //sum 20+35 from keyId related
    "totalFase2": 35
}
```

there is my example code, I'm confused sum data in 1 column:

```json
query = [
      {
        $match: {
          type: 'Fase1',
        },
      }, {
        $graphLookup: {
          from: 'invoices',
          startWith: '$key',
          connectFromField: 'key',
          connectToField: 'complement.payments.documentsRelated.keyId',
          as: 'payments',
          restrictSearchWithMatch: {
            'type': 'Fase2',
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          type: 1,
          total: 1,
          paymentData: '$payments.complement.payments'
        },
      },
];

db.getCollection('invoices').aggregate(query);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your code?

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 1):

Try `$map` to iterate loop of `payments.complement.payments.amount` array of array of amount, `$sum` array of amount, `$map` will return an array of number again `$sum` array of amount,

```
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      type: 1,
      total: 1,
      totalFase2: {
        $sum: {
          $map: {
            input: "$payments.complement.payments.amount",
            in: { $sum: "$$this" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cCuTm4LOKnh)